# How to set image size dynamically in ReactJS?

Tags: html, css

I have structure like this:

```css
img {
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
}

.cards {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 2em;
    width: 80%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    margin: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.info {
    padding: 1em;
    border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='cards'>
   <div class="card">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1004/5616/3744" alt="1004" />
     <div class="info">
       <h3>Greg Rakozy</h3>
       <div><small>https://unsplash.com/photos/SSxIGsySh8o</small></div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

on computers with long width image is rendered a little wrong.
[image]
how can I fix this so that it displays correctly, i.e. sticks to the '.card' block?

Comment: Looks ok to me in fullscreen mode on a 27" monitor

Comment: Elobrate exactly what are your needs??

Comment: in comps with 1900+ pixel width it renders wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to limit the width of you main container:

```css
.cards {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 2em;
    width: 80%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 1440px; /* whatever you desire */
    margin-left: auto; /* center the container */
    margin-right: auto; /* center the container */
}
```

Then each image should take 100% for it's container:

```css
.card {
    margin: 1em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
    object-fit: cover;
    flex: 0 0 25%; /* each card will be 25% width */
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can either put those images in a `div.img-container` and set the div *width* & *height* like this.

   .img-container {
   width: 100%;
   height: // as you want;
   }
   and then put that image inside `.img-container` and set the image *width* to *100%*.

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height 350px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.container .img-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.container .img-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container .card-info {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
  </div>
  <div class="card-info">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <small>Your link here</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. and either set image *width 100%* and *height auto*.

Answer (score 0):

Adding those to `.card` class

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Google how to make image responsive with css, it's not related to React.

Comment: width became very long. It takes 80% of body

Answer (score 0):

```
.card {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```